# Unable to see the added headers to HTTP request in Angular

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, httpclient

Following roughly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909747/1525840) and checking with Angular docs on [header manipulation](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers), I added the following interceptor class (as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers)).

NB. It gets invoked and other operation on the request object (like making it HTTPS etc.) work. However, the neither the added/appended nor the updated/set header seem to show.

```
export class CoolInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler)
    : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request.headers.append("Shazoo", "Hazaa");
    request.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/text");

    console.log(request.headers);

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

For some reason, the object displayed doesn't contain the manipulated headers. I'm getting the following.

> HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}

If I manually run `append` or `set` in the console, I see that the object changes a bit. Regrettably, it doesn't tell me anything useful that the `lazyArray` contains an element now nor why it doesn't contain anything while printed during the execution.

> HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: Array(1), headers: Map(0), lazyInit: HttpHeaders}

I've been reeding on this for a while and I believe I got it right, except something small misstake that I'm unable to detect or diagnose.

**How do I alter the headers object of my request in the interceptor?**

Or is the interceptor a poor choice of locations for such functionality, despite [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers)? That wouldfollow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989539/1525840). I've also seen [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45243757/1525840) suggest a different approach by `RequestOptions` and/or by altering the `this.http.get(...)` parameters of the injected `HttpClient`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40160010/1525840).

Comment: You cite the angular docs, *but you don't follow them*. You need to clone the request, change the clone (set the headers) and return that in the interceptor.

Comment: @R.Richards We are agreed regarding me not following the docs. I wasn't sure where precisely that I deviated. But now I see the double gotcha. Partly, I need to clone, just like it says. Partly, I have to manipulate the headers object according to its immutability, as suggested in the answer below. I tried both ways. Just not at the same time, hehe. Fell free to post it as an answer (or let me know so I can answer myself, although I see it as a tacky move).

Answer (score 2):

The `set` method on `HttpHeaders` doesn't mutate the object, but creates a copy. Therefore, while

```
    request.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/text");
```

won't work,
*[edit: `request` itself is immutable, therefore it needs to be cloned]*

```
    const clonedWithRequiredHeaders = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {"Content-Type": "application/text"},
    })
```

should.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work. The field `headers` is read-only and can't be assigned. CHeck the examples I've linked to on Angular page that discuss it.

Comment: You should clone the request first, then you can. (request.clone)

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, a double-sided gotcha, that thing. Now, that I got the help, I see clearly it being stated in the docs. I was definitely right claiming that I get the point right but get stuck on a minor, idiotic mistake. My bad, entirely, hehe.

Comment: @mbojko Pleaes update your reply according the comments. I'll be happy to accept it as the correct answer.